# Subject omission in a specific sentence

Tags: grammar

Can *it* be omitted in the following sentence:

> On the other hand, more than a century later there is no complete classification of solvable algebras, nor is *it* in principle possible to obtain complete classification to isomorphism classes.

?

Edit: This [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31858/omission-of-subject-after-such-as?rq=1) actually seems to be related:  When *is* it ok to omit subject?

Comment: We can't just leave **it** out. A subject is needed.  One could say "nor, in principle, is *obtaining* a complete classification possible".  Or simply "nor, in principle, is *a complete classification* possible."

Comment: Also, we would say "classification *of*" not "classification *to*".

Comment: Thanks @TRomano . As a sidenote, out of context it may seem that it should say "of" instead of "to" however, it would mean a different thing and is not actually right in my case.

Comment: "classification to classes" may be acceptable jargon in your discipline, but it's not idiomatic English.  Why is it "classification **of** solvable algebras" but "classification **to** ... classes"?

Comment: This is about sorting something into categories, algebras are sorted into classes, hence "classification of solvable algebras to isomorphism classes". I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I think you want to say **into** rather than **to**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, we can't omit *it* from the sentence. It is the subject of its clause.

Answer to edit: There  is no subject omitted in [the question you link to](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31858/omission-of-subject-after-such-as?rq=1) in your edit.

As far as when you can  omit the subject of a sentence or independent clause, the thing that comes immediately to mind are second person commands:

> (You) go there!
>
> (You all) please be quiet!

A person "commanding" *himself* to do things could use a similar form:

> Okay, relax, breath, stay calm.